# Ajax image preview before upload and form validation in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, codeigniter, upload

I want to preview image in placeholder before uploading a image and form validation using ajax in codeigniter

what i have done is shown in the below code first i wrote image preview code in javascript then ajax to submit the form details and getting the response from the controller and showing in the view

view->

````
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('items/itemsave', array('id' => 'uploadForm')) ?>
              <?php if (!empty($msg)): ?>
                <div class="alert <?php echo $msg_class ?>" role="alert">
                  <?php echo $msg; ?>
                </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
              <div class="form-group text-center" style="position: relative;" >
                <span class="img-div">
                  <div class="text-center img-placeholder"  onClick="triggerClick()">
                    <h4>Update image</h4>
                  </div>
                  <img src="../uploads/2.png" name="profileDisplay" onClick="triggerClick()" id="profileDisplay" style="width: 200px; height: 200px">
                </span>
                <input type="file" name="profileImage" onChange="displayImage(this)" id="profileImage" class="form-control" style="display: none;">
                <label>Profile Image</label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" >
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" >
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="buyingprice" id="buyingprice" class="form-control" placeholder="Buying price" >
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="sellingprice" id="sellingprice" class="form-control" placeholder="Selling Price" >
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="category" id="category" class="form-control" placeholder="Category" >
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="code" id="code" class="form-control" placeholder="Code" >
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" >
              </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="save_profile" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save User</button>
              </div>
            <?php echo form_close() ?>```

    javascript->
    ```<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#uploadForm").on('submit', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
                //e.stopPropagation();

                var contactForm = $(this);

                $.ajax({
                    url: contactForm.attr('action'),
                    type: 'post',
                    data: contactForm.serialize(),
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        if(response.status == 'success') {
                            $("#uploadForm").show();

                        }

                        $("#message").html(response.message);

                    }
                });
            });



        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function triggerClick(e) {
      document.querySelector('#profileImage').click();

    }
    function displayImage(e) {

      if (e.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
          document.querySelector('#profileDisplay').setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.files[0]);
      }
    }
    </script>
````

controller->

```
    public function itemsave(){


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('location','Location','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('buyingprice','buyingprice','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('sellingprice','sellingprice','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('category','category','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('code','code','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','description','required');

            $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; 
            $config['max_size']      = 2048; 
            $config['max_width']     = 1024; 
            $config['max_height']    = 768;  
             $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if($this->form_validation->run()==true && $this->upload->do_upload('profileImage'))
            {
                $response = array(
                    'status' => 'success',
                    'message' => "<h3>Category Added successfully.</h3>"      
                );
              }
            else
            {

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('profileImage')) {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
                $this->load->view('itemsadd', $error); 
              }

                $response = array(
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'message' => validation_errors()
                );
                }
            $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_output(json_encode($response));
    }
    }
```

Comment: so where is the problem? could you please explain what you are looking for as an answer?

Comment: when i m submitting the form the ajax success is not working so that i can show validation errors or success message after the form is submitted

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?? Please give us more clarity on what error you are getting. Have you checked the network tab in developer console while making an ajax call??

Comment: when i m filling all the form fields and submitting the form it is not getting submitted. it only works when i m removing e.preventdefault from ajax and when i m doing that that i m getting error message on the form action page not on the same page where form is written

Comment: try `url: '/items/itemsave',` attention to the leading backslash, that works if your controller is items.php in the controller folder and the function is itemsave()

Comment: @vicke its not working i think there is something in the javascript and ajax code because when i m removing e.preventdefault then the form is getting subbmitted but ajax is not working

Comment: it would help to know, what the browser console errors are, see the network tab, and are you calling jQuery correctly?